# include exclude leapyear based on fromdate and todate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope someone could help me on this...

I have this function and it is working as expected. It checks for leap year and takes 365 or 366 days accordingly.

**Problem:**  Instead of checking leapyear, I want to check the fromdate and todate and if any of these dates start on 29 Feb and the difference between fromdate and todate is more than 365 only then add +1 to daysInYear otherwise consider only 365 days. I will not have any periods where 2 leap year will be in the given fromdate and todate. so I am not worried about that scenario.Hope it is clear.

```
getDifference: function(fromdate,toDate) {
  var now = toDate || new Date();
  // days since the date    
  var days = Math.floor((fromdate.getTime() - now.getTime())/1000/60/60/24);
  var diff = 0;
  // iterate the years
  for (var y = now.getFullYear(); y <= fromdate.getFullYear(); y++){
    var daysInYear = opc.calculator.leapYear(y) ? 366 : 365;
    if (days >= daysInYear){
      days -= daysInYear;
      diff++;
      // increment the age only if there are available enough days for the year.
    }
  }
  return diff;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you don't mind adding a library to your code, have a look at: [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

You do something like:

```
moment().diff(moment('20140229', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'days');
// returns 417 today (2015-04-22)

// or

moment('20150422', 'YYYYMMDD').diff(moment('20140229', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'days');
```

It is a great library to work with time and date.

Comment: well, let me explore the possibilities.

Comment: thanks for sharing this library, I am going to select this as an answer because lot of requirements that we have right now are around date and time and this library will be good asset for the project, thanks